Why does cold weather feel more uncomforatable than very cold weather?
Just off the bat, I know (and used to believe) the theory that it's about humidity and wind speed (as e.g. discussed here) but I have started to have some serious doubts after considering a few more scenarios I've found myself in.
To describe the issue — if you're not already familiar with it yourself — I generally find cold weather (roughly -5 to 10°C) extremely uncomfortable, but very cold weather (roughly -20 to -5°C) feels great and exhilarating — to the point that I dislike going outside in late autumn, regardless of how I dress, but in mid winter I can go out in just a shirt and overcoat and feel great. Even below -20 it still feels great, just that at those temperatures you can't stay outside for long without your ears and nose going numb.
There are a few possible explanations I have considered:
1. Winter could be dryer and less windy than autumn, so the perceived temperature is actually higher.
This is the only answer I could find referenced, but I doubt this now, for a number of reasons:

It doesn't feel warmer at all. -20°C winter air hits you like a truck when you go out the door, but it's a nice truck :D.
I used to live in Saint Petersburg, which has cold winters and is right by the Finnish gulf (high humidity and strong winds), and that didn't seem to modulate the perception much. Winter there still felt a lot more fun than late autumn in southern Germany.
In any case the notion that very cold air is as a general rule warmer than cold air is ludicrous. If anything it would be a matter of how different weather conditions affect perception at roughly the same temperature.
If anything, at roughly the same temperature I think wind makes the cold air feel better.

2. It could just be humidity
It's possible that due to the vapor pressure of water at different temperatures -20 by the sea could still be less humid that 0°C far away from it. Sadly, though I notice this phenomenon every year, while I have often consulted the temperature I have never consulted the humidity, so it's hard to say whether 0°C would feel better at different humidities. However, if it's just a matter of how well the air drains heat from your body, I don't see why humidity but not wind speed would affect the perception.
3. It's about acclimation
I thought since winter follows autumn, maybe it's a question of finally getting used to the cold. This would make a lot of sense if it weren't that I still feel the same about different ranges when traveling to different places with no acclimation.
4. It's about emotional associations
Winter, and very cold air, are associated with fun activities, like skiing, skating, nice snowy scenery, christmas markets, new year's fireworks, etc. Autumn and slightly cold temperatures are associated with... nothing interesting really. So it could be that it's a matter of feeling better about the temperature than the temperature feeling better. Honestly this seems like a cop-out explanation, but I couldn't find a lot of better ones.
5. Fight-or-flight response
It could be that very low temperatures trigger a stress response in the body which can be enjoyable or at least overshadow the feeling of discomfort from the cold. I personally feel very energized in winter, so that might be why (though 4 could also explain this). I guess this is something that could easily be tested, but I haven't found any studies looking into this.
6. Perception range of cold receptors
It could be that TRPM8 receptors stop signalling at colder temperatures, and/or only get triggered at very low temperatures. From what I could gather TRPM8 starts signalling at 26°C in the interstitial space, not air temperature outside the body. I am not sure at what ambient temperature the interstitial space of lower skin layers drops to 26°C, but this answer would in any case mean that wind speed and humidity still play a role. Given that you can feel cold air and very cold air almost immediately (and tell the difference), it's possible that there exists at least one other receptor. I couldn't find out what such receptors might be, but it is possible that the sensation generated by TRPM8 could be considered enjoyable while sensations generated by other receptors less so (or the other way around).

In any case, I'm curious whether any of you know any good literature on cold perception, specifically focusing on why very cold temperatures might feel less aversive than slightly cold ones. Explanations 1 and 2 just seem to wave the issue away with a bit of half-assed thermodynamic wisdom, whereas things like 4 might be a bit too soft of a theory to be properly tested. I think 5 and 6 sound like the most promising ideas.
